# Force DOM element in "inspected mode"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In Chrome, if one right-clicks a DOM element and selects "inspect element", then one is brought to the "Elements" tab of the debugger. In addition, the JavaScript variable `$0` becomes populated with the "inspected" DOM element.

Given a DOM element, is there a way to have JavaScript force the browser to "inspect" it, so that the browser fills in the value for `$0` natively, without doing the assignment ourselves?

Comment: Why do you not want to assing it yourself?

Comment: But you can do it yourself without any "user action". `var $0 = myElement`.

Comment: @Oriol: Have you tested it? I'm not sure it's that simple.

Comment: So you are trying to open the debugger from javascript code? I doubt you can do that

Comment: @Bergi: No. I open the debugger myself. I just want to force Chrome to populate the `$0` variable for me.

Comment: So you open the debugger with the menu (or Ctrl+Shift+I) instead of in the context menu of an element, and want it to default-select a given element?

Comment: @Bergi: That's one possible application, yes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console), the Chrome Web Developer supports [Firebug's Command Line API](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API). And one of the methods present there is [inspect](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Inspect) which does what you want.

Unfortunately, that is a *Command Line* API, which means that it's only valid in the console, at the command line, not from in-page scripts. There's no way to control the web developer tool from an in-page script, other than through the [Console API](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API) which provides mostly logging facilities.

Comment: Looks like the variables live as properties in `console._commandLineAPI`, which is accessible through the console but not through a script on the page.